# Создать сложный sql запрос в Rails-приложении

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Всем привет! Есть приложение на рельсах, в нем, в частности, есть таблица пользователей (модель User) и таблица отзывов (модель Reviews). В таблице Reviews есть поле rating (оценка пользователя). Настроено отношение один-ко-многим, т.е. у пользователя может быть много отзывов. Нужно настроить запрос, чтобы помимо необходимых полей из таблицы пользователей возвращалось еще и поле, содержащее средний рейтинг пользователя из таблицы Reviews:

```
@search = User.select("id, name, username").joins(** средний рейтинг **)
@search[0].rating 

# возвращено некоторое значение
```

Отмечу, что это поле нужно, чтобы далее отрендерить его в json, т.е. вариант с коллбэком

```
after_find do |user|
  user.rating = user.reviews.count == 0 ? 0 : user.reviews.sum(:rating)/(user.reviews.count)
end

attr_accessor :rating
```

не работает. Всем заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть смысл воспользоваться существующей в SQL функцией AVG, а не пытаться посчитать всё вручную. JOIN нужен левый, чтобы в выборку попали пользователи без отзывов

```
User.select(
  'users.id, users.name, users.username,
  COALESCE(AVG(reviews.rating),0) AS avg_rating'
).joins('LEFT JOIN reviews ON reviews.user_id = users.id')
  .group(:id)
```

PS: любые коллбэки сильно усложняют жизнь разработчика и всё время норовят выстрелить ему в ногу, не стоит их использовать по любому поводу

UPDATE:
Использовать алиас для where не получится by design. Попробуйте так:

```
User.select(
  'users.id, users.name, users.username,
  COALESCE(AVG(reviews.rating),0) AS avg_rating'
).joins('LEFT JOIN reviews ON reviews.user_id = users.id')
  .where('COALESCE(AVG(reviews.rating),0) >= ?', params[:min_rating].to_i),
  .group(:id)
```

Или почитайте про WITH и напишите уже весь запрос на чистом sql :)

Comment: Спасибо за реализацию, еще бы подсказали, как потом в этом запросе фильтровать пользователей по минимальному рейтингу.

Comment: Если мой ответ вам помог, то примите его, пожалуйста. В смысле, вам их нужно отсортировать по `avg_rating`?

Comment: Да. Иначе я бы не заморачивался: мне нужно добавить что-то  вроде where('avg_rating >= :min_rating', min_rating: params[:min_rating].to_i), однако этот кусок не работает

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич, обновила свой ответ

Comment: В любом случае спасибо, пошел вспоминать SQL )